Cartoon similar to Transformers and Voltron with big animal robots
Some time in the 90's maybe early 2000's.
It was a TV cartoon show featuring these people who would man these huge robot animals and ride around in them. Not sure on the plot but it basically involved fights between various factions with different animal robots (potentially some flying ones? I can't remember exactly).
Sorry to be so vague, but does anyone who has any idea what i'm talking about?

Might this be Transformers: Beast Wars? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_Wars:_Transformers

@AvnerShahar-Kashtan though the same but didn't remember if people ride them.

Zoids was a franchise, that had a TV show in the late 90s and before/after that as well. It featured huge robot animals, mostly cats/dog type, from what I remember. They weren't technically robots either but living entities made of metal that just happened to look like robots. 
More specifically, Zoids: New Century, was dubbed in English and aired in the US in 2001. According to the wiki, the story revolved around the Blitz team fighting their numerous rivals. 
It could have also been, Zoids: Chaotic Century, this aired in the US a year earlier, 2000, but the story revolved around nations at war not smaller factions. 
